# Scrolling multiple list view together

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've a carousel page, each page has the same structure with a listView. My question is: 
is it possibile to scroll the different listViews in different pages together?

Comment: The listviews have the same objects? Because you could use ScrollTo method from listview

Comment: the listviews have the same structure with the same data type but the objects are different and loaded dinamicaly. This isn't a problem because i can save the index instead of the object and retrieve the correct element of the list. I tried to save the scroll position using the event itemAppearing/itemDiseapparing and save the index in a common variable but this events are fired also when i change the page of the carousel page changing the correct value of the variable.